# CS50 Mario (More Comfortable) Error Messages

Tags: c, cs50

What is wrong with my code? I'm currently getting these messages (sad faces are the errors):

```
:) mario.c exists
:) mario.c compiles
:) rejects a height of -1
:( handles a height of 0 correctly
   \ expected an exit code of 0, not output of "  \n"
:( handles a height of 1 correctly
   \ expected output, but not "   \n#  #\n"
:( handles a height of 2 correctly
   \ expected output, but not "    \n #  #\n##  ##\n"
:( handles a height of 23 correctly
   \ expected output, but not "                         \n            ..."
:) rejects a height of 24    
:) rejects a non-numeric height of "foo"
:) rejects a non-numeric height of ""
```

The program seems to work fine other than being exactly the way CS50 is looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    int height;
    int i;

    do {
        printf("Height:");
        height = get_int();
    }while(height < 0 || height > 23);

    int x = height;
    int y = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < height + 1; i++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            printf("%s", " ");
        }

        for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("%s", "  ");

        for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

        printf("\n");
        x = x - 1;
        y = y + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"What is wrong with my code?"* It uses `<cs50.h>`... Hi there! I spent less than an hour auditing the code underlying libcs50 and in this time I found at least four bugs. A few of those weren't fixed; as the devs and I failed to come to agreement with regards to the theoretical abstraction known as "leaks", for example, only the simpler *obvious* bugs (i.e. the buffer overflows) were fixed. Nonetheless, I recommend avoiding libcs50, and its corresponding resources in favour of more traditional textbooks, as cs50 seems to rely upon numerous technical issues.

Comment: I'm taking an online course for cs50 since there aren't really any other good resources I've found (although there probably are many out there). I don't have courses in person available and this course teaches based on that library. Do you have any advice on how I could learn how to program in C (from ground 0) if not through this course?

Comment: *"... there aren't really any other good resources..."* According to who? Are you speaking from the perspective of an expert who can spot misleading information, or from the perspective of a student who can't?

Comment: *"Do you have any advice on how I could learn how to program in C (from ground 0) ...?"* Yes! From *ground 0*, which I gather means *no prior programming experience what-so-ever*, I've seen no decent materials to get you straight to C, hence you should learn a *procedural programming language* which *doesn't have undefined behaviour* (e.g. Python or Javascript, C# or Java, etc). This will give you enough of an introduction to read a traditional textbook such as K&R2E. Don't forget to do the exercises...

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll look into that. I phrased that statement horribly, but I meant to say that I did not come across any that seemed to have the comprehensive introductory curriculum that cs50 did in a structured format with notes and problem sets. Keep in mind, I did not look at every resource out there so an expert would definitely know more than me as I'm practically a complete beginner.

Comment: All the more reason you should look to an expert for advice. I *don't* consider myself an expert, as I haven't written a C compiler... but [at least I can cite my understanding](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/issues/67#issuecomment-301962527), where-as it appears those mostly in control of maintaining libcs50 (including Malan), *can't*! When your lead developers can't cite the standard for the language you claim to teach, that's not good news...

Comment: Note that I've conducted reviews for other organisations; Pearson VUE (cppinstitute.org) seemed more comprehensive, though similarly invalid a few years back when I reviewed that... I'm waiting on account score reset so I can review it again. Hopefully they've fixed some invalidities, then I might have something more comprehensive and less invalid to recommend.

Comment: Here on SO, we have pretty poor experience from the C part of CS50. For example people studying CS50 seem to have a much harder time understanding how strings work than those who study through traditional books. That being said, CS50 is not nearly as horrible for learning C as K&R. Probably best to avoid both.

Comment: It is odd to use an outer loop indexing with `i` and then to use `i` in multiple inner loops.  That's a bug of some sort.  The height 0 problem arises because you use `for (i = 0; i < height + 1; i++)` in the outer loop, which goes through the set of inner loops once when it should do so zero times.  I suspect you're outputting too many blanks, but I've not looked at the specification of the problem — no-one here should have to find the PSET on the CS50 web site.

Answer (score 0):

Try including an if statement after the user inputs height. That will at least get you the proper result for a height of 0.

```
if (height == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Those /messages are key to fixing your code. You've got this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

    int number;
    do 
    {
         number = get_int("Height:");
    }
    while (number < 1 || number > 8); 

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) 
    {
         for (int j = number - i - 2; j >= 0; j--) 
         {
            printf(" ");
         }
         for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
         {
            printf("#");
         }
         printf("  ");
         for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
         {
            printf("#"); 
         }
         printf("\n");
     }
  }
```